# Oracle user cannot see any content in ALL_MVIEW_COMMENTS

Tags: sql, oracle

I've set up a minimal user with the following grants:

```
CREATE USER X IDENTIFIED BY X;
GRANT CONNECT TO X;
GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO X;
```

[According to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3), the `SELECT ANY TABLE` privilege should grant:

> Query tables, views, or materialized views in any schema except SYS,AUDSYS. Obtain row locks using a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE.

And indeed, I can see the materialised view I've created in another schema:

```
SELECT owner, mview_name FROM all_mviews;
SELECT owner, mview_name FROM all_mview_comments;
```

The first query yields:

```
OWNER   MVIEW_NAME
------------------
TEST    M_LIBRARY
```

But the second query doesn't yield any results with user `X`. It does produce the same materialized view with user `TEST` or `SYS`. A workaround would be to (but I don't want to do that):

```
GRANT SELECT ON TEST.M_LIBRARY TO X;
```

Is that a (known) bug in Oracle? Or some additional grant missing?

Answer (score -1):

You can not see comments that are made on the `MVIEW` (of another schema) using `all_mview_comments` as it shows only `MVIEWS` that are owned by you.

It is clearly mentioned in the [oracle documents](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1099.htm#REFRN20341) as following:

> ALL_MVIEW_COMMENTS displays comments on the materialized views
>   accessible to the current user.

Let me show you by example:

Creating `MVIEW` and comment on `MVIEW` from user **tejash**:

```
C:\Users\Tejash Hingu>sqlplus tejash

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Nov 15 16:14:19 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Fri Nov 15 2019 13:04:48 +05:30

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MVIEW_LUKAS
  2      BUILD IMMEDIATE
  3      REFRESH
  4          FORCE
  5          ON DEMAND
  6  AS
  7      SELECT
  8          *
  9      FROM
 10          EMPLOYEES;

Materialized view created.

SQL> COMMENT ON MATERIALIZED VIEW MVIEW_LUKAS IS 'Here is your demo.';

Comment created.
```

Checking data in `ALL_MVIEWS` and `ALL_MVIEW_COMMENTS` table from **tejash** user

```
SQL> SELECT OWNER, MVIEW_NAME
  2  FROM ALL_MVIEWS;

OWNER  MVIEW_NAME
------ ------------
TEJASH MVIEW_LUKAS


SQL> SELECT * FROM ALL_MVIEW_COMMENTS;

OWNER    MVIEW_NAME   COMMENTS
-------- ------------ --------------------
TEJASH   MVIEW_LUKAS  Here is your demo.
```

**SEE!!! `ALL_MVIEW_COMMENTS` contains data from same schema.**

Giving grants to user **T** (`GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO T;`)

```
C:\Users\Tejash Hingu>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Nov 15 16:18:02 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO T;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Now, Checking data in `ALL_MVIEWS` and `ALL_MVIEW_COMMENTS` table from **T** user

```
C:\Users\Tejash Hingu>sqlplus T

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Nov 15 16:18:24 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Fri Nov 15 2019 16:09:04 +05:30

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> SELECT OWNER, MVIEW_NAME
  2  FROM ALL_MVIEWS;

OWNER    MVIEW_NAME
-------- ------------
TEJASH   MVIEW_LUKAS

SQL> SELECT * FROM ALL_MVIEW_COMMENTS;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

**SEE!!! `ALL_MVIEW_COMMENTS` do not contain any data from different schema.**

Hope!! It is clear now.

Cheers!!

Comment: Cheers to you, too! I can see the `MVIEW` in `ALL_MVIEWS`. I gave the user access to the materialised view using the `SELECT ANY TABLE` privilege.

Comment: Yes, that is what the difference is. You can see the MVIEW in `all_mviews` but in `all_mview_comments`, you can not see the `mviews` that are owned by other users. also please note that you are able to select the data from `all_mview_comments` but you are not able to see anything there. If you create any `MVIEW` and comment on `MVIEW` in your own user(X) then you will be able to see it here.

Comment: That makes no sense :) Again, the `SELECT ANY TABLE` grant gives *access* to all tables (and materialized views) to my user `X`. The view (both views, in fact) are supposed to list all materialized views that are *accessible* to the current user `X`. I should see it there, and indeed, if I grant access *explicitly* (please, re-read my question), then I can see it.

Comment: See my updated answer and what is written in oracle documentation exactly matches

Comment: You didn't answer my question yet, also, I don't think you are correct with your assertion that this behaviour is documented. `T` has access to `MVIEW_LUKAS`, so `T` should see it in `ALL_MVIEW_COMMENTS`. To illustrate this, just `GRANT SELECT ON MVIEW_LUKAS TO T` and query `ALL_MVIEW_COMMENTS` with user `T` again (as mentioned in my question)

Comment: When you have grant to select from `MVIEW` then it means owner of `MVIEW` trust you and allows you to see everything regarding `MVIEW`. hope you are getting my point.

Comment: And I hope you're getting my point that I believe you don't actually *know* the answer and just improvise :) Anyway, thanks for trying.

Comment: Ok. Lets keep it that way. But my understanding on it is that when you have the rights to select the mview then only you will be able to see the details of the mview. I.e. comme the mview. And I came to know about this when I gave online screening exam for interview in one of the reputed company where there was the same question about this behavour and they also accepted my answer. Anyway, thanks for looking into the answer and hope future reader will find it helpful.